# IEEEtranN how to list only one author in text body

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, bibliographystyle

**Edit: Solution found. I need to use natbib package.**

I like family name of the first author to appear in the referencing text body, e.g.

> [Smith et al. (1999)] done this and that

when using IEEEtranN, the following output is produced

> [Smith et al. (1999)Smith, Author2 and Author3] done this and that

How can I fix this behavior? Or any other alternative bibliography styles?

Example Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {J. Smith and F. Author2 and S. Author3 and F. Author4},
  year = {1999},
  title = {What Smith and others done},
  publisher = {Journal Of This and That},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key} done this and that. 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

output:

> [Smith et al.(1999)Smith, Author2, Author3, and Author4] done this and
> that.
>
> **References**
>
> [Smith et al.(1999)Smith, Author2, Author3, and Author4] J. Smith, F.
> Au-thor2, S. Author3, and F. Author4,What Smith and others done.
> JournalOf This and That, 1999.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: `IEEEtranN` is supposed to be used together with `\usepackage{natbib}`. The symptoms you are describing are consistent with not having loaded `natbib`. Note that `IEEEtranN` says that it is **Not for normal IEEE work**. So if you are preparing a document for IEEE submissions you probably should be using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` and not `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`.

Comment: Many thanks! it works. Yes I am just writing a technical report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in [`IEEEtranN.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtranN.bst) say

```
%% IEEEtranN.bst
%% BibTeX Bibliography Style file
%% Natbib version of IEEEtran.bst
%% *** Not for normal IEEE work ***
```

Hence, `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}` should be used together with `natbib` (and should *not* be used if you prepare a paper for submission to the IEEE).

So either load `\usepackage{natbib}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author    = {J. Smith and F. Author2 and S. Author3 and F. Author4},
  year      = {1999},
  title     = {What Smith and others done},
  publisher = {Journal Of This and That},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{key} done this and that.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith et al. (1999) done this and that.]

or switch from `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}` to `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author    = {J. Smith and F. Author2 and S. Author3 and F. Author4},
  year      = {1999},
  title     = {What Smith and others done},
  publisher = {Journal Of This and That},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{key} done this and that.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] done this and that.]

Comment: I am writing only a technical report. The latter solution is not desired since I find referencing by family names the most appropriate.